# Xamarin.Android - Form Transparent

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, transparent

In Xamarin Android, how to make a form completely transparent?

In my layout XML....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id ="@+id/LLBack"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my OnCreate...

```
LinearLayout ll = FindViewById<Android.Widget.LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LLBack);
ll.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);`
```

but dont work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style to file styles.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
      <style name="AppTheme1" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

                        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

                        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

                        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

                        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

                        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

                        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

                        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

                        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

                  
      </style>
</resources>
```

And apply the style to your activity:

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Exported = true,Theme = "@style/AppTheme1" )]
```

Comment: Hi @Samara Bravo, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.